# How can I make YX5300 MP3 player play song in a loop?

Tags: sensors

I am doing a Christmas project and I have an ultrasonic sensor that detects if a person is In front of it. I want that if someone is in front of it, it lights up LEDs, which it does, and it also has to play a Christmas song, which it doesn't. I tried to make it play the Christmas song but nothing happens. Also the LEDs are only blinking when you put ur hand in front of the ultrasonic sensor. I want it to light up the lEDs for the same amount of time the song is, 28 seconds, and than the lEDS should stop and the ultrasonic sensor should wait for another person and it repeats. I am new to this so please be specific in your reccomendations.
Here is my code:

```
#define trigPin 10
#define echoPin 13
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define ARDUINO_RX 7//should connect to TX of the Serial MP3 Player module
#define ARDUINO_TX 6//connect to RX of the module
SoftwareSerial mySerial(ARDUINO_RX, ARDUINO_TX);
static int8_t Send_buf[8] = {0} ;
#define CMD_SEL_DEV 0X09
#define DEV_TF 0X02
#define CMD_PLAY_W_VOL 0X22
#define CMD_PLAY 0X0D
#define CMD_PAUSE 0X0E
#define CMD_PREVIOUS 0X02
#define CMD_NEXT 0X01

int red1 = 5;
int red2 = 4;
int green1 = 3;
int green2 = 2;

long lCnt = 0;
unsigned long lStart;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin (9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(red1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green2,OUTPUT);
  delay(500);//Wait chip initialization is complete
  sendCommand(CMD_SEL_DEV, DEV_TF);//select the TF card  
  delay(200);//wait for 200ms


}


void loop(){
  float duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);


  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) * 0.0344;

  if(distance > 0 && distance <=60){



    digitalWrite(red1,HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(red2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(green1,HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(red1,LOW);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(red2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(green2,HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(green1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(green2,LOW);
    delay(50);
    sendCommand(CMD_PLAY_W_VOL, 0X1E01);
  }


}

void sendCommand(int8_t command, int16_t dat)
{
  delay(20);
  Send_buf[0] = 0x7e; //starting byte
  Send_buf[1] = 0xff; //version
  Send_buf[2] = 0x06; //the number of bytes of the command without starting byte and ending byte
  Send_buf[3] = command; //
  Send_buf[4] = 0x00;//0x00 = no feedback, 0x01 = feedback
  Send_buf[5] = (int8_t)(dat >> 8);//datah
  Send_buf[6] = (int8_t)(dat); //datal
  Send_buf[7] = 0xef; //ending byte
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++)//
  {
    mySerial.write(Send_buf[i]) ;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the command `[Single cycle play]` which is `7E FF 06 08 00 00 01 EF` (the `00 01` towards the end is the song number to play).

All the commands are detailed in [the manual](http://geekmatic.in.ua/pdf/Catalex_MP3_board.pdf).

Comment: Where should I put that in my code?

Comment: @elimar008 in place of your current play command. You may want to add a set volume command as well.